# prove that $G/(K \cap N)$ is isomorphic to $(G/K) \times (G/N)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Question: $G$ is a group, $K$ and $N$ are normal in $G$. $KN=G$. Prove that $$ G/(K \cap N) \cong (G/K) \times (G/N)$$

Define $\phi:G \rightarrow (G/K) \times (G/N)$ by $\phi(g)=(gK,gN)$.

then $\phi$ is a surjective group homomorphism. We can use the 1st Isomorphism Theorem to show the result, but we need to prove that $\ker(\phi)=K \cap N$ first.

$\ker(\phi)=\{g \in G \mid \phi(g)=(1_{G/K},1_{G/N}) \}=\{g \in G \mid  (gK,gN)=(K,N) \}=\{g \in G \mid g \in K \ \text{and} \ g \in N \} = K \cap N$

Is my solution correct? I don't believe in my solution because i did not even use the fact that $K$ and $N$ are normal and $KN=G$.

What's wrong with my solution?

Comment: Why is the map surjective? This is not obvious.

Comment: For starters, how do you know that this $\phi$ is surjective?

Comment: In fact, you use $KN=G$ implicitly in the conclusion that $\phi$ is surjective. $K$, $N$ is normal in $G$ then $G/K$ and $G/N$ are groups.

Comment: @GAVD He didn't make it explicit.

Comment: @GAVD you mean KN=G implies that phi is surjective? how? i thought it's obvious

Comment: Its not obvious. You have to show that for all $g_1,g_2$, there exists a $g$ s.t. $(gK,gN)=(g_1K,g_2N)$, where $g_1$ and $g_2$ may be different. You have to use the condition that $G=KN$.

Answer (score 1):

**Lemma** Let $L, M \unlhd G$ and suppose $G=LM$ and $L \cap M=1$. Then $G \cong L \times M$.

**Proof** Oberve first that each $g \in G$ can be written *uniquely* as $g=lm$ with $l \in L$ and $m \in M$. For if $g=lm=l'm'$, then $(l')^{-1}l=m'm^{-1} \in L \cap M=1$. Hence $l=l'$ and $m=m'$.

Secondly, note that $L$ and $M$ commute with each other: if $l \in L$ and $m \in M$, then $l^{-1}m^{-1}lm=(l^{-1}m^{-1}l)m \in M$ since $M$ is normal. Also $l^{-1}m^{-1}lm=l^{-1}(m^{-1}lm) \in L$, since $L$ is normal. Hence $l^{-1}m^{-1}lm \in L \cap M=1$, so $lm=ml$.

Now define a map $f: G \rightarrow L \times M$ as follows: $f(g)=(l,m)$, where $g=lm$ is the unique decomposition of $g$ as elements of $L$ and $M$. The previous remarks above show that actually $f$ is a well-defined homomorphism, which clearly is bijective.

For the situation described in the post: apply this to the normal subgroups $K/(K \cap N)$ and $N/(K \cap N)$ of the group $G/(K \cap N)$ and you are done.